"$" is being removed when used bash inside groovy
I am using bash script inside Groovy in the Jenkins pipeline. Jenkins job is parameterized and using a password parameter option named "PASSWORD". The issue is when password contains "$" sign, then it is getting escaped in the bash script. For example: Actual password inputed is "ppa$$worddd" but in the bash script $PASSWORD value is "ppa$worddd". As we could see one "$" is removed. Please look at the code below. Please help
def password = params.get('PASSWORD')
stage('execute') {
            steps {
                script {
                    println password // - Here value is "ppa$$worddd" as expected
                    withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'ID', variable: 'C_ID'),string(credentialsId: 'SE', variable: 'C_SE')]) {
                        if (!starsValue.isEmpty()) {
                            sh '''
                              cd Scripts
                              echo $PASSWORD // - Here value is "ppa$worddd" .As seen one "$" is removed
                            '''
                        } 
                    }
                }
            }
        }


Use single quotes, replace "ppa$worddd" by 'ppa$worddd'!

How to do that, $PASSWORD is the variable

@Karthick, where you are setting PASSWORD environment variable? your code snippet is not stowing this. according to documentation you can do something like environment { PASSWORD=password } before sh command to set env variable https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#using-environment-variables

something along: def PASSWORD = System.getenv("PASSWORD")
if (PASSWORD) { println "The value of PASSWORD is: ${PASSWORD}"} else { println "PASSWORD is not set." }  should suffice unless you've a specific use case for spawning to the shell

Under some very specific circumstances Jenkins does variable expansion. Syntax is arbitrary, but somewhat documented here. I think at some point they wanted to ignore $$ combinations, but then some random patch "improved" on that idea and now we have what we have.
There is no way to disable this variable expansion, you can only avoid it by doing seemingly equivalent things that for some reason bypass it:
withEnv(["PASSWORD=${params.PASSWORD}"]){
    sh 'echo $PASSWORD'
}

